# Custom colors gplotmatrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, customization, matlab-figure

I'm trying to use the function gplotmatrix of MATLAB to create a scattered plot. The problem is that I want to set the colors of the groups using the RGB codes instead of the default colors of Matlab.

For example in the line

```
gplotmatrix(x,y,group,clr,sym,siz,doleg,dispopt,xnam,ynam)
```

I have to use something like

```
clr = 'rb'
```

if I have two sets and I want to change the colors in Red and Blue.

So I'm asking if instead of declaring `clr` as a string with the default colors letters, is there an alternative like in the classic `plot` command where I can declare the colors in RGB, for example as `[1 0.2 0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by declaring RGB colors in two rows like this: `[0 1 0.3; 1 0.2 0]`

**Example:-**

```
load discrim;

figure;
gplotmatrix(ratings(:,1:2),ratings(:,[4 7]),group,...
    [0 1 0.3; 1 0.2 0],'.o',[],'on','',categories(1:2,:),...
    categories([4 7],:))
```